# Incorrect syntax near "case"

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2016

I have one table having data like this:

```
 ID | Fill
  ---------------
  1  |  @@@@
  2  |  @@@@Y
  3  |  @@@@Y245
```

I want to insert the above data into another table and expecting the result table to be:

```
  ID | Fill
  ----------------
  1  |      (Space)
  2  |      Y
  3  |      Y245
```

That is, when i find @@@@, it should be replace by space (4 space char as it has 4@)

Here is how I'm trying to do this:

```
   insert into table1
    (
   id

   ,case
       when contains(substring([fill],1,4),'@@@@') then '    '+substring([fill],5,100)
       else [fill]
       end 
    )
    select
    id
   ,convert(char(100),[col1]+[col2]+[col3]+[col4])
      from 
     table2
```

However, its showing syntax error near "case". What am I doing wrong? how can i achieve the desired result?

Comment: `CONTAINS` is a free text search operator, it seems you're looking for `when [fill] like '@@@@%'` ?

Comment: Additionally, your syntax is just plain wrong. `insert into table (list of columns to insert into) select query here`, you've placed the case expression inside "list of columns", which is wrong. So yeah, incorrect syntax.

Comment: Look at `patindex`. Also look for generic questions about stripping/trimming leading characters.

Answer (score 2):

Just use `replace()`

```
insert into destination_table (col1)
select replace(col1, '@', ' ' ) from source_table
```

If `@` occurs, it will be replaced. If not, then the original string is used.

Comment: The substring I have used, because I want to find out the exact position of @ where I can insert a space. Like wise, I have few different character also at different position. I would like to replace the few chars with other chars (based on the position)

Answer (score 0):

The case is in the field list part of the INSERT statement and is therefore not valid. 
You could just use a simple replace to achieve this

```
INSERT INTO table1 (id, fill)
select id, replace(fill, '@@@@', '    ') from table2
```